# Edit root files

Tags: root-access, text-editor

I have installed Jota text editor on my rooted device but Jota isn't give root permission when started and I can't save edited files. I tried to clear the app and data cache to no avail. How can I manually give Jota text editor root permission?

Comment: You cannot manually give root permission if the app is not designed to make use of it. Are you sure Jota asks for root access? Try switching to another editor. As an example, QuickEdit app can save files requiring root access.